# Hashing function object

Tags: python, function, hash

I am trying write some code to generate unique hashes for each function call that return a different output. The function is deterministic and the value of its output only depends on the input parameters.

```
import os
import functools
import hashlib
import numpy as np
import inspect


def generate_hash(dictionary):
    args = []
    for key,item in dictionary.iteritems():
        if key == 'self': continue
        if isinstance(item,functools.partial):
            args.append((key,inspect.getsourcelines(item.func),
                generate_hash(item.keywords)))
        elif inspect.isfunction(item):
            args.append((key,inspect.getsourcelines(item),generate_hash(item.__dict__)))
        elif isinstance(item,np.ndarray):
            args.append((key,item.data))
        else:
            args.append((key,item))

    return hashlib.sha224(str(args)).hexdigest()

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, axis):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

        self.axis    = axis
        self.ft_func = lambda ft: np.mean(ft,axis = self.axis)

    def extract(self,ft,ft_func):
        _cache = generate_hash(locals())
        if os.path.isfile(_cache):
            # Load data from cache
        else:
            # Compute data, cache
        return _cache
```

From the example you can see that for different values of `ft` the hash returned by `extract` will change. but modifying the value of `Foo(axis=X)` won't affect it. Reason being, I need to determine the const values of `ft_func` within generate_hash and use them to create the hash.

For example:

```
foo = Foo(1)
print foo.extract(1,ft_func=foo.ft_func) -> 1a72fe1d0...

foo = Foo(2)
print foo.extract(1,ft_func=foo.ft_func) -> 1a72fe1d0...

foo = Foo(2)
print foo.extract(2,ft_func=foo.ft_func) -> 504307731...
```

I thoroughly read the documentation of the module [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) without finding a solution.

Any suggestion?

**Python memoization**: pointed out on a different thread, yes, it's the same idea, but I couldn't find an implementation that is persistent across different session.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you getting the source code?

Comment: Create a unique hash of a function object? Is that enough? What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: You can create that hash, but of course *all* the input of a function will determine its behavior, and the globals it uses is part of its input.  What I want to say is:  The value of `value` *should* not go into your hash as it is not part of the function.

Comment: I guess what @Ngenator wanted to know is what you are trying to achieve in the end.  Generating unique hash values of functions is a very versatile thing and can be used for several different tasks, each having different aspects.  Providing information on what you want to achieve in the end probably gives us the means to give you alternatives to using unique hashes of functions.

Comment: Still I don't think the question was unclear. Anyway, answering your question, you're right, I am not interested to hash the function itself but its behavior and that is why I need to somehow "preprocess" its body.

Comment: End goal it to avoid calling the function twice if I already know it will return the same output (e.g. numpy arrays) which is stored somewhere on my hardrive.

Comment: @memecs Much, I'll take a look when I have a chance.